# Python - extracts nested json not working

Tags: json, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with nested json, I tried to read it in different ways and something goes wrong.
Structure json below.

[Link to file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7dab405c26628d98c21950661f87cd5420200702103849/deced6)

I care about "leads" the most

I tried the following but I still get the error (KeyError: 'leads')

```
df = json_normalize(dane['data'],record_path='leads')
```

What should I use to get the data in the form of a table?

Comment: I get still errors on your input data after I corrected `'answer2` -> `'answer2'`

Comment: definitely something wrong with the input data. Curly braces are missing around `'paging: ...` and after that closing square bracket is missing to close the list.

Comment: I corrected json :)

Comment: Still the same error? If so, it is panda related which I don't have installed. Maybe someone else can help you further from here.

Comment: I saved the json to a file, see if you can see correctly now ?

Comment: Are you able to help ?

Comment: thx, I've solved the problem